# Generate both expanded and compressed css files in Compass with Grunt

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-compass

I'm using `grunt-contrib-compass` to compile my SCSS files, and here's the Gruntfile configuration for the same.

```
    compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                watch: true,
                imagesDir: 'web/assets/img',
                sassDir: 'web/assets/scss',
                cssDir: 'web/assets/css'
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see that I'm using Compass' "watch" option to watch for files for change. So all files within `scss` folder are compiled and eventually, one main file `styles.css` is generated within `css` folder. While I can use `outputStyle: "compressed"` option for Compass task to generate all CSS files minified, I want those files to remain expanded.

So is there anyway I can generate original files as expanded while an additional file `.min.css` which is compressed?

An alternative solution I have as of now is to avoid using `watch` of compass, and rely on `grunt-contrib-watch` and `grunt-contrib-cssmin` instead. But `grunt-contrib-watch` is much slower compared to that of Compass.

I cannot have another watch task running to monitor CSS files and run `cssmin` when they're changed, since starting `compass` with `watch: true` will block any other following tasks (unless I use something like [Grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent), which I want to avoid).

Any help is appreciated.